# "System Policy prohibits use as a Hotspot" when trying to turn on WiFi hotspot (option grayed out)

Tags: 20.04, thinkpad, hot-spot

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on ThinkPad x230, W540, T440p, etc.

Sometimes (appears randomly) after a reboot, I try to click on "Turn on WiFi hotspot..." under WiFi settings, but it is greyed out and when I hover over it, it says "System Policy prohibits use as a hotspot".

Why is this?

Comment: Same issue here on a Dell Precision 7530. I believe it might be a bug. For me, switching tabs in settings (for example, to "Network") and back makes Turn on WiFi hotspot work again.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 57):

reported [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/965), try switching to another settings panel (ie "Network") and then back, it seems to enable the option again for most.

Comment: Honestly shocked this worked for me, well done!

Comment: Sadly, in my case it did not work.

Comment: Interesting. It works on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Two years later, this is still the working solution in Ubuntu 21.10. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

It's only periodically disabled; to re-enable simply click on the "Network" in the left pane - making sure the OS realises you have a network connection. Then go back to WiFi and voila you have the ability to create a WiFi HotSpot. You don't have to create a separate network for this.

Comment: This worked for me. Although I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: works here as well! thanks!

Comment: Lol, it really worked. can you anyone tell me what really happened here?

Answer (score 2):

This is also happened in my machine as well. So what I did is I have created hotspot network and connected via hidden network.
For that, Normal wifi setting will not give this setup. So 
follow these instructions 
1. `Press alt+f2`
2.You will see a popup window where you need to type follow command to get wifi setting window

```
nm-connection-editor
```

3.You need to press + icon to create a hotspot network
[image]
4.After that, You have to select WIFI option
[image]

5. You need to change the mode to hotspot and SSID as you prefer
   [image]
6. Save the setting then open wifi setting
7. select the network you have created
   [image]
   [image]
8. Click connect to hidden network
   [image]
9. Select your network which you have created
   [image]
10. After you connect your hotspot you can see below like picture
    [image]
    Congrats you enable your hotspot

Comment: This makes sense and does work for turning on the hotspot but seen clearly in step 8 is the `Turn on WiFi hotspot...` option still grayed out. This answer, while helpful, is unfortunately just a workaround.

Comment: @TR_SLimey, After you connected your hotspot using connect to hidden network. It will not show that
you will need to do the 9th step and 10th

Comment: @TR_SLimey If you think, It helpful please upvote it

Comment: I just tested this and I do in fact have to do step 9 and 10 each time. "Turn on hotspot" remains grayed out. However, since this is a valid workaround and seems to provide an adequate solution, I will upvote. Nevertheless, it seems that this is simply a bug with Ubuntu which should be fixed.