# Turn on WiFi Hotspot greyed out 22.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04

I am unable to create a WiFi hotspot on 22.04. I upgraded from 21.10 when 22.04 was made available through updates. No matter what I do, the option does not appear in black. I am using a LAN cable to connect.

[image]

I tried the [trick described for 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266042/turn-on-wi-fi-hotspot-greyed-out-in-20-04) in another question without luck. Any help will be great. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this [other trick](https://askubuntu.com/a/1238148/167115)? From what they describe, the option will still be greyed out but somehow it works.

Comment: I tried selecting " Network " in settings first and the one that talks about trying to connect to a hidden network. The problem is the issue remains the same. There is no visible hotspot SSID and the option remains greyed out. Thanks