# Unable to connect to Ethernet internet after trying to enable Hotspot

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I had my Ethernet working but the hotspot button has been disabled after Ubuntu installation.

[image]

to handle that I tried following the steps of [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214452/turn-on-wi-fi-hotspot-disabled-in-ubuntu-18-04)

To my surprise, now even my Ethernet has stopped working. I have deleted the conenction that I have created but the problem is still there.

I get `?` (Question Mark) on my Ethernet icon . The LAN works when I connect to windows laptop. What settings do I need to revert ?

[image]